# Slack delayed message integration with Node TypeScript and Lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless, slack-api

I started implementing a slash-command which kept evolving and eventually might hit the 3-second slack response limit. I am using `serverless-stack` with `Node` and `TypeScript`. With [sst](https://docs.serverless-stack.com/) (and the vscode launchfile) it hooks and attaches the debugger into the lambda function which is pretty neat for debugging.

When hitting the api endpoint I tried various methods to send back an acknowledgement to slack, do my thing and send a delayed message back without success. I didnt have much luck finding info on this but one good source was this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49395831/4421557) - unfortunetly it didn't work. I didn't use `request-promise` since it's deprecated and tried to implement it with vanilla methods (maybe that's where i failed?). But also invoking a second lambda function from within (like in the first example of the post) didn't seem to be within the 3s limitation.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if attachinf the debugger is just taking to long etc.
However, before attempting to send a delayed message it was fine including accessing and scaning dynamodb records, manipulating the results and then responding back to slack while debugger attached without hitting the timeout.

Attempting to use a post

```
export const answer: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (
    event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2, context, callback
) => {


    const slack = decodeQueryStringAs<SlackRequest>(event.body);


    axios.post(slack.response_url, {
        text: "completed",
        response_type: "ephemeral",
        replace_original: "true"
    });


    return { statusCode: 200, body: '' };
}
```

The promise never resolved, i guess that once hitting return on the function the lambda function gets disposed and so the promise?

Invoking 2nd Lambda function

```
export const v2: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (
    event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2, context, callback
): Promise<any> => {

    //tried with CB here and without
    //callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: 'processing' });

    const slack = decodeQueryStringAs<SlackRequest>(event.body);
    const originalMessage = slack.text;
    const responseInfo = url.parse(slack.response_url)

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        ...slack,
    })
    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda()
    const params = {
        FunctionName: 'dev-****-FC******SmE7',
        InvocationType: 'Event', // Ensures asynchronous execution
        Payload: data
    }

    return lambda.invoke(params).promise()// Returns 200 immediately after invoking the second lambda, not waiting for the result
        .then(() => callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: 'working on it' }))
};
```

Looking at the debugger logs it does send the 200 code and invokes the new lambda function though slack still times out.

Nothing special happens logic wise ... the current non-delayed-message implementation does much more logic wise (accessing DB and manipulating result data) and manages not to timeout.

Any suggestions or help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

*Quick side note, I used `request-promise` in the linked SO question's answer since the JS native Promise object was not yet available on AWS Lambda's containers at the time.*

There's a fundamental difference between the orchestration of the functions in the linked question and your own from what I understand but I think you have the same goal:

**> Invoke an asynchronous operation from Slack which posts back to slack once it has a result**

Here's the problem with your current approach: Slack sends a request to your (1st) lambda function, which returns a response to slack, and then invokes the second lambda function.

The slack event is **no longer accepting responses** once your first lambda returns the 200. Here lies the difference between your approach and the linked SO question.

The desired approach would sequentially look like this:

1. Slack sends a request to Lambda no. 1
2. Lambda no. 1 returns a 200 response to Slack
3. Lambda no. 1 invokes Lambda no. 2
4. Lambda no. 2 sends a POST request to a slack URL (google incoming webhooks for slack)
5. Slack receives the POST requests and displays it in the channel you chose for your webhook.

Code wise this would look like the following (without request-promise lol):

### Lambda 1

```
module.exports = async (event, context) => {
    // Invoking the second lambda function
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda()
    const params = {
        FunctionName: 'YOUR_SECOND_FUNCTION_NAME',
        InvocationType: 'Event', // Ensures asynchronous execution
        Payload: JSON.stringify({
            ... your payload for lambda 2 ...
        })
    }
    await lambda.invoke(params).promise() // Starts Lambda 2

    return {
        text: "working...",
        response_type: "ephemeral",
        replace_original: "true"
    }        
}
```

### Lambda 2

```
module.exports = async (event, context) => {
    // Use event (payload sent from Lambda 1) and do what you need to do

    return axios.post('YOUR_INCOMING_WEBHOOK_URL', {
        text: 'this will be sent to slack'
    });
}
```